# How to use a custom validation method taking request parameters

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a really simple form on which I'm doing some validation:

```py
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()

    start = cleaned_data.get("start")
    end = cleaned_data.get("end")

    if start >= end:
        raise ValidationError("start should not be greater than end.")
```

But I need to add another validation (which is based on the user making the request).

I tried to add the parameter to the clean method:

```py
def clean(self, user):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()

    start = cleaned_data.get("start")
    end = cleaned_data.get("end")

    if start >= end:
        raise ValidationError("start should not be greater than end.")

    if not user.email.endswith("@example.com"):
        raise ValidationError("blah...")
```

Unfortunately, I cannot call the is_valid() in the view with a parameter:

```py
if form.is_valid(request.user):
   ....
```

I get the following error message:

> is_valid() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I also tried to add a new method to the form:

```py
def validate_email(self, user):
    if not user.email.endswith("@example.com")::
        raise ValidationError("blah...")
```

and call it from the view:

```py
if form.is_valid() and form.validate_email(request.user):
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.created_by = request.user
    obj.save()
```

In that case, the exception really gets thrown and crashes the application.

My goals are:

- to make the validation dependant on a criteria in the request
- to display an error message *normally* when the validation fails

What would be the correct way to implement the custom validation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a simple mixin class

```
class FormContextMixin:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.context = kwargs.pop("context", {})
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and then use the `FormContextMixin` class with your *form class* as

```
class AlbumModelForm(FormContextMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        # doe something with `user`

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Album
```

Thus, you can initialize the form with any arbitrary data as

```
form = AlbumModelForm(request.POST, context={"request": request})
```